# Передача указателя на метод в другой метод

Tags: c++

Как это правильно реализовать ?

```
class CInterface
{
public:
    CInterface();
    void AddToQueue(std::string name, void(* func)());
    void DelFromQueue(std::string name);
    bool CheckInQueue(std::string name);
    // ----
    void Work();
    // ----
    std::map<std::string, void(*)()> m_InterfaceQueue;
};

CInterface::CInterface()
{
    this->AddToQueue("Work", Work); 
    // ошибка E0167 аргумент типа "void (CInterface::*)()" несовместим с параметром типа "void (*)()
    // Если делаю в определении метода void(CInterface::* func)(), то получаю ошибку C3867  "CInterface::Work": нестандартный синтаксис; используйте "&", чтобы создать указатель на член
    // В случае же если сделать передаваемый метод, в данном случае "Work" статичным, то все работает.



}

void CInterface::AddToQueue(std::string name, void(*func)())
{
    if (this->CheckInQueue(name))
    {
        return;
    }
    this->m_InterfaceQueue.insert(std::pair<std::string, void(*)()>(name, func));
}

void CInterface::DelFromQueue(std::string name)
{
    if (!this->CheckInQueue(name))
    {
        return;
    }

    this->m_InterfaceQueue.erase(name);
}

bool CInterface::CheckInQueue(std::string name)
{
    if (this->m_InterfaceQueue.find(name) != this->m_InterfaceQueue.end())
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

void main()
{
    CInterface gInterface;
}
```

Comment: 1. `void(*func)()` не может быть указателем на метод. 2. Для получения указателя на метод в С++ всегда требуется явное применение оператора `&` и указание квалифицированного имени метода, т.е. не `Work`, а обязательно `&CInterface::Work`. 3. `int main()`, а не `void main()`.

Answer (score 0):

Как то так

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CInterface
{
public:
    CInterface();
    void AddToQueue(std::string name, void(CInterface::*func)(void));
    void Work();
};

CInterface::CInterface()
{
    this->AddToQueue("Work", &CInterface::Work); 
}

void CInterface::AddToQueue(std::string name, void(CInterface::*func)(void))
{
    cout << name << endl;
    (this->*func)();
}

void CInterface::Work()
{
    cout << "I'm working";
}


int main() {
    CInterface c;
    return 0;
}
```